# Переполнение стека в android программе. мало кода

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdk

Учусь делать свои виджеты. В `layout` сделал это.

```
    <com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
```

вот функция, где мы задаём текст для виджета.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val text = """
        hello.
    """.trimIndent()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val ownTextView = findViewById<OwnTextView>(R.id.customView)

        ownTextView.text = text
    }
}
```

вот сам виджет.

```
class OwnTextView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): View(context, attributeSet) {
    val paint = Paint();
    var text = ""
    set(value) {
        text = value
    }

    init {
        paint.color = 0x000000ff
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawText(text, 0f, 0f, paint)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

Выводит в лог такую запись, пока стек не переполниться.

```
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
2021-01-04 16:57:48.058 9072-9072/com.xverizex.customtest0 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.OwnTextView.setText(OwnTextView.kt:14)
        at com.xverizex.customtest0.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setter` ушёл в рекурсию.
`text = value` - на котлине это вызов сеттера (внутри сеттера - это вызов самого себя).
Определение сеттера только для того чтобы присвоить значение - лишнее, у свойств есть геттер/сеттер по дефолту.
Если по какой-то причине нужно обратиться к свойству из его геттера/сеттера, то следует использовать  вместо имени спец. ссылку `field`:

```
    var text = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html